# Creating shortcut to run text file in xterm

Tags: shortcut-keys, xterm

Simple question.  Under custom keyboard shortcuts I have tried xterm ~/Desktop/folder/subfolber/textfile but that does not work.

It's my understanding that keyboard shortcuts are terminal commands.  When I enter the above in terminal nothing happens, so I probably have the wrong directory.  But if I type sh ~/Desktop/folder/subfolber/textfile in terminal I can run the text file, but then this shortcut does not work if I try and add it via keyboard options.

Any clarification is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "run a text file"? Is it a bash script ? If you want to open a text file, you can do it with a text editor, like `gedit`. `gedit /path/to/your/file`

Comment: No clue what you are trying to schieve, but you cannot use `~` in a `.desktop` file. Use absolute paths instead.

Comment: If I type sh ~/Desktop/folder/subfolber/textfile in terminal

Comment: The file is a shell script.  I just realized this, but all the "sh" terminal is an abbreviation for shell.  When Jacob mentions absolute paths I assume that it should be /home/[user name]/Documents/whatever instead of ~/Documents?

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard shortcuts are commands but they belong to `daemons`, such as `gnome-settings-daemon` or `unity-settings-daemon`.  In case of X-server in general, regardless of which GUI you use, shortcuts may be altered with `xbindkeys` app.

However, in your specific case, what you really need to make xterm open and run a script is the following:

1. Go to Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom;
2. Add a new shorcut; tell it to run `xterm` with full path to the script , e.g., `xterm -hold -e /home/user/bin/myScript.sh`
3. Assign keypress to it.

Note: script must be made executable with `chmod 755 /path/to/script.sh`

Here's my example:

Script in `/home/serg/testScript.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "This was a triumph\nI'm making a note here, huge success"
df
date
```

Shortcut setup

[image]

Output

[image]

Check out my other answers that assign scripts to shortcuts:

- [Program to take 2/3 and 1/3 of screen?](https://askubuntu.com/a/678716/295286)
- [Terminal Short-cut ctrl + alt + T, 2 terminals, different size](https://askubuntu.com/a/586977/295286)
- [How can I automatically add workspaces, only if I need them?](https://askubuntu.com/a/676116/295286)

Comment: Don't forget to leave an upvote if you like my answer ;)

Comment: Really a fantastic answer.  This is why I like this site.

Comment: Arg... well I thought it was working.   I can execute the script from a shortcut now, and can use     printf     to display a message in xterm, but oddly enough it don't open the program.  My script looks like #!/bin/bash
printf "Testing 123"
sh ~/Desktop/java/jgrasp/bin/jgrasp'    The odd part is if I enter just 'sh ~/Desktop/java/jgrasp/bin/jgrasp' into xterm it will execute correctly.

Comment: Does it work if you give it full path instead if using ~ ?

Comment: Still no luck with the full path.  Does it matter in which directory the script is?  I mean as long as the shortcut has the correct path.

Comment: OK, so I downloaded the zip file with jgrasp, added the same command you had and it works fine for me.  The `/home/user/jgrasp/bin/jgrasp` is a script , so you may want to check the permissions on that file with `ls -l`. Also you don't need `sh` part in the command, giving the path to file itself will do; otherwise you're creating one too many processes