# Does Lubuntu 19.10 provide "Auto-resizing and snapping windows"?

Tags: unity, gnome, lubuntu, window-manager, lxqt

On Ubuntu there is a nice feature that allows windows to auto-resize (for example to half-screen width) and be "magnetized" to the corners of the screen. Lubuntu on the other hand does not appear to have this feature. Is there a way to achieve this by installing some package but without installing another desktop environment in place of LXDE?

---

I've just found a related question where a fix is proposed: [Is there a lightweight way to snap windows in Lubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73536/is-there-a-lightweight-way-to-snap-windows-in-lubuntu) However the post is a few years old. Is this solution still up to date?

Comment: There is no LXDE packages for that. In fact, it's more about windows manager wich is by default on LXDE "openbox".

Comment: @JerareYoshi Thank you for your comment. Then what can I do to obtain the desired effect with openbox?

Comment: There is no such effect.

Comment: @Pilot6 I've just found a related question where a fix is proposed: https://askubuntu.com/questions/73536/is-there-a-lightweight-way-to-snap-windows-in-lubuntu However the post is a few years old. Is this solution still up to date?

Comment: I think the solution is probably still up to date since openbox related doesn't change too much.

Comment: @Riku Oh, great to know. I hate this feature, but it's good to know.

Comment: Short answer is "yes,can be done", but long answer is that it requires scripting and making the script work with keybindings. Back when I used to use openbox myself, I've written a few scripts for resizing and repositioning windows with `wmctrl` ( you can read about it here https://askubuntu.com/q/94859/295286 )  and I think this is  one of those  https://askubuntu.com/a/678716/295286 Adding keybindings can be done via specific xml file, http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings    So yes, possible, but probably not easy

Comment: You haven't said what release, but given LXDE hasn't progressed in years, little has changed (prior comment asking about "*post is a few years old*") with Lubuntu's Next (LXQt) first provided with 15.04 even if it only hit mainstream last year (18.10 release).  I'd suggest @SergiyKolodyazhnyy is possibly your best bet (*I'd want release detail to think of more*)

Comment: @guiverc The latest version: Lubuntu 19.10. And thanks for your advice.

Comment: Have you seen https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182097/lubuntu-19-10-how-to-tile-windows-the-window-tiling-section-is-missing-in-lxqt?

Comment: @JusticeforMonica Do I understand correctly that these are manual shortcuts but the windows do not resize/snap automatically?

Comment: Yes, when you want to snap a window horizontally or vertically, you need to tell the system that by pressing the appropriate keybinding. Or do you want something that automatically positions windows somewhere? You'll need to make that clear by editing your question.

Comment: @JusticeforMonica I would like to achieve the same effect as in Ubuntu, where the snapping/resizing to half-screen of the windows is automatically obtained by just dragging them or double clicking on them.

Comment: Then maybe Ubuntu is the best choice. Lubuntu, being simpler by design, purposely doesn't come with all the features present in distros such as Ubuntu.

Comment: Or you could try Kubuntu which does what you want.